# BottomNavigationView is empty

Tags: android, gradle, bottomnavigationview

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPV8xA7m-iw) for adding a `BottomNavigationView` to my Android Studio project.

I migrated my project to AndroidX and noticed the `BottomNavigationView` he is using in the video might not be compatible with AndroidX, so I decided to use `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'` instead.

### The problem

Upon adding my `BottomNavigationView` and setting up all the relevant attributes, I see that it's still empty, despite following all instructions and checking that everything is correct.

Notice how the BottomNavigationView is completely empty and has a height of 0
[image]

This is my activity's XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/frameLayout"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my menu items' XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda"
        android:title="a funny item"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/favoritesButton"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
        android:title="favorites"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ideaButton"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda"
        android:title="ideas"/>
</menu>
```

What's wrong here? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

add in your dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
```

style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

menu xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/homeButton"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda"
            android:title="a funny item"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/favoritesButton"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
            android:title="favorites"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ideaButton"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda"
            android:title="ideas"/>
    </menu>
```

Comment: Copy and pasted everything, rebuilt the project and now it works. Just wish I would know *why* it didn't work. Android Studio is so frustrating to use sometimes.